# Curl cmd command returns Internal server error

Tags: python, curl, post, request, fastapi

I have this simple code for testing:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
import requests

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', status_code=200)
def index():
    return {'message':'Hello, World!'}

@app.post('/', status_code=201)
def index_post():
    dicti = request.form.to_dict()
    print(dicti['key'])
    return {'message':'Hello, Post!'}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        "views:app", 
        host="localhost", 
        port=5000,
        reload=True    
    )
```

And I want to check if the post works. I ran in the cmd this:

```
curl --request POST  -d'{"key":"it works","pas":"la"}'  http://327ffe2d90b9.ngrok.io/
```

But instead of printing it works in the terminal as I was expecting, it returned Internal Server Error.

Comment: This means the server fails, you  may access server log to see the stacktrace